# JSONDecoder with multiple date formats?

Tags: swift, request, combine, dateformatter

I have 2 type date from api. I need to decode together. But I didn't find any solution. I need to add `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` format in this code. How can I do this?

```
    func run<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest, _ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> AnyPublisher<Response<T>, Error> {
    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .tryMap { result -> Response<T> in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(self.dateFormatter)
            let value = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
            return Response(value: value, response: result.response)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify when you'd need to use format1 and when format2? In same JSON? In different ones? Do you know exactly where they are used, or do you have to try if one succeed? Depending on that, the answer would be different.

Comment: `func run` working for all my project. But only one different json result (different struct) return different time format. I don't want to add more function for one result.

Comment: It depends. You have the parameter `JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()`, I'd put the parameter with its dateFormatter instead here and wouldn't override it in the `trypMap()`, or simply add a DateFormatter parameter to your method.

Comment: Where can I put it? When I don't put it here, json with this date return blank.

Comment: Various possible ideas: https://pastebin.com/sZse166b

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is a custom `dateDecodingStrategy` with `ISO8601DateFormatter` which is able to specify the date format depending on the given string

```
func run<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest, _ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> AnyPublisher<Response<T>, Error> {
return URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .tryMap { result -> Response<T> in
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom { decoder -> Date in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
            let dateString = try container.decode(String.self)
            if !dateString.hasSuffix("Z") {                            
                dateFormatter.formatOptions.remove(.withTimeZone) 
            }
            if let isoDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
                return isoDate 
            } else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Wrong Date Format")
            }
        }
        let value = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
        return Response(value: value, response: result.response)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thank you its working but this line return error `return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) ?? throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Wrong Date Format")` I used like this  `return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!`

Comment: I wouldn't do that, it causes a crash if the date format doesn't match the two formats. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom decoding behavior by implementing `init(from decoder: Decoder)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types